# How to format code

Tags: support, edits

I find this web site extremely difficult to use.

How do I add code? I have spent the last two hours trying to post a question, but can't because of some type of editing of code. I have a Spring XML file that contains close to a hundred lines of code. I can't indent the code because it has extended lines.

Is there ANY way I can post without indenting a hundred lines of code? Is there ANY way to override that editing requirement?

I've had to just give up before because it was going to take too long.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask (including all linked material) and [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If you have to post 100 lines of code you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 9):

> indenting a hundred lines of code?

Sounds like you have too much code there. I cannot imagine anyone reading a question with a hundred lines of code, parsing the code, understanding it and then still having the energy to answer.

You are doing a disservice to yourself and those who would answer your question by not making your code an [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

But, to answer you question - the feature exists. Select your lines of code and then click the "Code Sample" button `{}` on the editor toolbar, or use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>.

I would still urge you to trim down your code to a minimal example that shows the issue (if a hundred lines *is* a minimal reproduction, I'd suggest that Stack Overflow isn't a good place for the question).

Comment: You like the sscce better than the on-site [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Both are good ;)